# Share image on social networking site in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to share edited image on social netwrking site so which API i use to share image to webpage using c sharp in windows phone 8

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`ShareMediaTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharemediatask):

```
ShareMediaTask smt = new ShareMediaTask();
smt.FilePath = "image.png";
smt.Show();
```

The limitation is that for security reasons, the `ShareMediaTask` only supports photos from the Media Library (like the Camera Roll or the Saved Pictures folder). See the question here for more info: [Usage of ShareMediaTask along with Isolated storage image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855377/usage-of-sharemediatask-along-with-isolated-storage-image)