# Is it possible to Share a PDF file from isolated storage using ShareMediaTask in WindowsPhone8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to share a PDF file,which is stored in isolated storage.Is it possible to Share a PDF file from isolated storage using ShareMediaTask in WindowsPhone8?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read online ShareMediaTask has no access to the IsolatedStorage
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855377/usage-of-sharemediatask-along-with-isolated-storage-image)