# Add App icon in share option list when share any picture from gallery in windows phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sharing

I want to add my app icon in share list. When a user share any picture from gallery by holding that picture and press on share... option. There is a list like Bluetooth, Email, Facebook, WhatsApp etc... I want to add my app icon along with those option. Please tell me how can i do this?

Thanks
Nishant

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff967563(v=vs.105).aspx) from MSDN. This should answer your question.

For this you need to add an Extension to the the `WMAppManifest.xml` file and map the launch URI to your app. The article includes the details.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `Share Media Task` to share the image/icon you wanted to.

A great reference would be [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4aac15/sharing-image-from-windows-phone-8-app/) and also you could go through the sample from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207027(v=vs.105).aspx)

[Usage of ShareMediaTask along with Isolated storage image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855377/)

Hope it helps!